# Exceptions with more than one inner exception and using streams

Tags: java, exception, java-stream, throwable

How can i process A Multi exception Exception on a file with multiple issues to be reported.

I have a case of multi processing step where different exceptions can occur (e.g they will be made asynchronous later). I am using (might be anti-pattern for fail fast) list of exceptions then once they are completed and check for exceptions

I have my own customized exceptions category (For each asynch tasks) (extends `Exception` class) but implements an interface to have additional information like a key value pair specific to the message

Sample Implementation

```
List<Files> Folder;
//Now processed into below folders
List<Files> EnglishFolder;
List<Files> KoreanFolder;
List<Files> SpanishFolder;

//Now each task accumulates own exceptions.

EnglishException extends Exception implements InfoMapping 
{    
   private EnumMap<CUSTOMENUM,STRING> info;    
   EnglishException(String message){super(message);} 
   EnglishException(String message, Exception why){super(message);}    
   public void addInfo(CUSTOMENUM key,String value){info.add(key,value} 
}
```

My problem is if I know what issues i create these exception objects in each tasks but i don't throw them. But if there are general exceptions i just catch them and add it as

```
List<EnglishException> englishErrors;
//blah blah
englishErrors.add(new EnglishException("I found this error"));
//if generic exception in catch
englishErrors.add(new EnglishException("Unknown English error",e));
//returns without throwing exception
```

Now i need to synch up all tasks

neatly package all exceptions into an XML file

so i need to support 1 exception class that supports a list of `Exceptions class` has only this `Exception(String message, Throwable cause)` only supports single inner exception.

2 questions:

1. Should I implement another interface and have a special exception
   class implementing that and override innerException to be list? or
   am i missing something in java that supports multi inner exceptions? or any 
   other sound practice for doing this?
2. Being new to streams, can i make the above logic more readable/simple like
   (am very naive to java 8, just reading so forgive me if it doesnt
   make any sense). Not looking to get answers, may be just pointers to what in 
   streams to look for to achieve this.

   `Streams.Of(englishExceptionList,spanishExceptionList)`

   `.reduce(parentException)`

   `.ifAny(throw parentException)`

Comment: [`Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-)

Comment: @Holger good fit for my usecase. If you can add it to answers, I can mark it my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) which allows an arbitrary number of throwables to be recorded (and later retrieved via [`getSuppressed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed--)) and is also a better fit semantically than recording the other throwables as “cause”.

Since this is a kind of modification of one of the throwables, `reduce` is not the correct operation for that (and it would not provide the intended result in a parallel operation).

This doesn’t look like an operation that needs an optimization for a high number of elements, hence, the best solution is to straight-forwardly collect all elements into a `List` and use

```
if(!listOfAllExceptions.isEmpty()) {
    Throwable t = listOfAllExceptions.get(0);
    listOfAllExceptions.subList(1, listOfAllExceptions.size()).forEach(t::addSuppressed);
    throw t;
}
```

<sup>The type of `t` needs to be adjusted to an unchecked or declared exception</sup>.